How to add current git branch to commad promt in MSYS UCRT bash?
While in Cygwin and nearly every other *nix, I have used the following code within my .bashrc, for years.
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[00;33m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n\$ '

which generate a colored prompt when in a git folder.
# xxxx@LAPTOP /cygdrive/c/dev/some_git_repo (master)

However, trying the same in any of the MINGW64, MSYS, UCRT64 fails, to inject the parse_git_branch result. It seem that those shell simply refuse to execute the function. So clearly MSYS devs are doing something weird here. (I also noticed there are other weirdness in interpreting single and double quotes.)
I also tried:
# PS1='\[\e]00;\w\a\]\n\[\e[00;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[00;35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[00m\]  \[\e[00;33m\]\w\[\e[01;31m\] $(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\] \n\$ '

# Error: 
# -bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
# -bash: command substitution: line 1: `parse_git_branch)'

Q: How can I restore showing the git branch I am in, in these shells?

What happens if you change your PS1 setting to PS1='$(date) '? Assuming that works, add parts of your original PS1 back til you identify which construct is causing the problem then you can investigate why. In general to investigate why anything is failing, get rid of any occurrences of 2>/dev/null as that will hide error messages and add set -x so the shell tells you what's being executed.

Just tried with date, and it works, also with the 2>....

OK, if it worked with just $(date) now try it with just $(parse_git_branch). Still work? Now try it as PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n\$ ' or some other subset of what you want and so on until you find this construct is causing the breakage.

The reason to remove 2>... is so you can see any output to stderr to help debug any issue, not to make it work or not.

You can use PROMPT_COMMAND. Check out the Bash-Prompt-HOWTO.
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1_GIT_BRANCH=$(parse_git_branch)'
PS1='...${PS1_GIT_BRANCH}...'


Interesting work around that also works.

If you have other issues with command substitution in your shell, please check your Bash version by typing [CTRL+x] [CTRL+v], with or echo "$BASH_VERSION".  Then go to the official Bash site and look in the NEWS and CHANGES for recent issues/fixes.

Crazy enough, trying the old school back-tick [`] instead of $(command), worked!
The solution is to use, single quotes and back ticked command substitution.
PS1='\[\e]00;\w\a\]\n\[\e[00;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[00;35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[00m\]  \[\e[00;33m\]\w\[\e[01;31m\] `parse_git_branch`\[\e[00m\] \n\$ '


FWIW my git bash terminal in Windows is MINGW64 and I don't have a problem like that (and it's hard to believe it'd be a general problem with that platform). Along with "I also noticed there are other weirdness in interpreting single and double quotes." it sounds like you have some other problem with your environment and this is just putting a band-aid on this particular wound but not fixing the cause of it so it'll hurt you in other ways going forward.

I'm not using git-bash terminal, I'm using the out-of-the-box ones from the MSYS installation, with the windows install of Git. On my Cygwin terminal it works fine as always, but these ones are doing something else. Looking at the error message above, it seem that it find the closing occurrence of ) unexpectedly. I also found that many of the very sexy prompts from others, are also using back ticks. This seem to indicate that quotation handling is broken in MSYS bash. I also checked and compared all my shopt's and the relevant ones are the same.

I only mentioned git bash as it's using one of the platforms you thought might be buggy, MINGW64, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Since you tested PS1='$(date) ' and that worked, the problem is almost certainly simply something else in the string you're setting PS1 to rather than some platform breakage regarding quotes. Don't assume that any other code you see using backticks is written for any other reason than whoever wrote it didn't know any better.

You are right! There must be something from the control characters polluting the processing. I just tried again with the PS1='$(parse_git_branch) ' (same as above) and it works... I think this is a bug worth investigating, if outside control sequences can influence the execution of an independent function...

Yes, it's worth investigating but it's almost certainly simply a bug in your code. Let's say you wrote echo foo*. If you run that in a directory that contains no file names that start with foo it'll output foo*. If you execute it in a directory that contains the file foobar then the output will be foobar. If you set nullglob it'll output nothing. And so on... All cases where a piece of code is influenced by extrenal changes and all due to the bug in the code - it should be echo 'foo*' instead of echo foo*. My point is - the bug is almost certainly in the way you wrote your code

@EdMorton Hi Ed, I have now investigated, and it seem that something is broken in the later Bash versions. If you type [CTRL+x] [CTRL+v] you will see your bash version string. In my Cygwin it shows:  5.2.21(1)-release (x86_64-pc-cygwin) and in MSYS: 5.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys). I can say with confidence that it is related to this because the Bash change log and news both mention issues with command substitution.

So, what is your minimal PS1 value that reproduces the problem?

I found the culprit! Removing the very last newline \n fixes the problem. That NL is causing the $(xxx) to "double" execute. First, it sees xxx and executes it, places the results within the $() and then tries to execute it again (the previous results).

Problem is that the results are not clean as there is an EOL sanitation issue here. I was hoping to execute something bad, but there's more garbage there. These guys \n\$ are making the command substitution unhappy.

Are you saying that when you do  PS1='$(date) \n ' or PS1='$(date) \$ ' the command runs fine but if you do PS1='$(date) \n\$ ' you see date execute and then the shell attempt to executed the output from date? If so, that is what you should ask a new question about.

Is it possible that you have the PROMPT_COMMAND variable populated and that is what you see additionally executing? Try unset PROMPT_COMMAND before hitting enter to see if that changes anything.

Yes it was set to PROMPT_COMMAND=history -a, but clearing it, the issue persist.
